# What the command is for extracting 2 columns from existing data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a data.frame with 5 columns and wish to extract two of the columns into a separate data.frame.

Now I wish to create 2 data frame with each respective gender (so a subset of the previous data)

I have already extracted the columns gender and heights, but wish to create 2 data frames with (female and heights) and(male and heights)

Comment: There's several ways, but the easiest is to use the following syntax ``mtcars[,c("mpg", "cyl")]``

Comment: I have to print a summary for heights male and female seperately

Comment: what would be the syntax for that. Btw that previous command .was helpful, just need to divide the data by gender now. Summary for heights of males and females seperately

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please read this and share an example of your data + the code you were using: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Now I wish to create 2 data frame with each respective gender (so a subset of the previous data)

I have already extracted the columns gender and heights, but wish to create 2 data frames with (female and heights) and(male and heights).

Comment: Please give an example of your data.frame, e.g. via `dput`. Also it would be helpful to see what you did already and what you still want to do (e.g. by posting how the output should look like) to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend including example code in the future, but I think I understand what you're going for.

There's many ways to do this, so I'll mention a few and why you'd pick this method.

Method 1 (The one I would use most likely):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data %>% nest_by(gender)
```

You're left with a tibble (like a data.frame) with 2 columns 1 is gender and the other is data containing the heights you want. Now you can iterate over the data column using functions like `lapply` or `map`. Then get what you need and reduce it down. Keeps everything together and can reduce the amount of typing.

Method 2 (The just subset it method):

```
data_female <- data[data$gender == "Female", ]
data_male   <- data[data$gender == "Male"  , ]
```

The con of this is you can't use lapply or map functions to iterate over the two sets of data. If you're going to treat them completely separately and do completely different things with the data this is probably your best bet